# How to prove that $f(x) = g(-x) \implies f'(x) = -g'(-x)$?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Repeating the question

> How to prove that $f(x) = g(-x) \implies f'(x) = -g'(-x)$?

So far what I came up with was:

Let $h > 0$, then

$$\begin{align}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} & = \frac{g(-x-h) - g(-x)}{-h} \\
& = -\frac{g(-(x+h)) - g(-x)}{h} \\
& = -\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}
\end{align}$$

But seems like it is still far from proving the proposition. How should I proceed?

Comment: The first $=$ is wrong ...

Comment: **Hint** use the chain rule

Comment: You're very close, save a typo in the first equality (why did the bottom $h$ become negative?) - just write out $f'(x)$ from the definition as you've done, and write out the definition of $-h'(-x)$ as well, probably using a different variable, $\varepsilon$ instead of $h$ for your infinitesimal change. Follow your nose to show equality.

Comment: @DerekAllums Yes, sorry, I've just realized that I'd been using $h$ for both constant  and a function. The reason why $h$ is negative: $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}  = \frac{g(-x-h) - g(-x)}{(-x-h) - (-x)} = \frac{g(-x-h) - g(-x)}{-h}$. Is it wrong?

Comment: @Nelver Yes, that would be wrong. We are swapping out $f(x+h)$ with $g(-(x+h))$ and $f(x)$ with $g(-x)$, both things that we are told doesn't change any values. There is no need to touch the denominator at that stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Consider the following equalities valid for $h\not=0$,
$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{g(-(x+h)) - g(-x)}{h} = -\frac{g(-x+(-h)) - g(-x)}{(-h)}.$$
Now take the limit on both sides as $h\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the chain rule instead of proving it by the definition.
Take h(x)=-x and therefore, f(x)=g(h(x)). Now apply the chain rule : f'(x)= g'(h(x))⋅h'(x)= g'(-x)⋅(-1)=-g'(-x).

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve your mathematical expressions.